# Getting auto escape characters in Custom Helper

Tags: model-view-controller

I've created a custom Helper but I'm getting the tags auto escaped.

So for example instead of:

```
<a href
```

I got:

```
 &lt;a href
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer, I should return a MvcHtmlString and not a string